# Shadowbox YouTube video not appearing on iphone devices

Tags: iphone, html, css, flash, youtube

http://www.execairshare.com/about-us/testimonials

Has anyone had problems with loading a youtube video in shadowbox and being unable to view it on iphone?  On other mobile devices it works fine but on the iphone it just shows a blank black box.  I am assuming it is a flash thing?

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/Mf5Mpd1LIgM" rel="shadowbox:width=680;height=480">
<img src="//i4.ytimg.com/vi/Mf5Mpd1LIgM/default.jpg" alt="Thumbnail">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linking to a Flash version of the Youtube video. Since iPhone has no flash it doesn't work.

You'll need to link to HTML5 version of the video.

Try adding '?html5=1'

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/Mf5Mpd1LIgM?html5=1" rel="shadowbox:width=680;height=480">
<img src="//i4.ytimg.com/vi/Mf5Mpd1LIgM/default.jpg" alt="Thumbnail">
</a>
```

Comment: This is correct but you must put the value in an iframe I figured out.